# fancybox having issue with asp.net server control

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am using a jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js for opening a user control as a pop up. My parent page has server control like drop downs. When I click on cancel (cross mark). It closes the fancy box and my page gets loaded without postback, but none of my server controls are firing the server event.

I don't want my parent page to reload on click of cancel.

I have a user control and that user control has an anchor and two drop down (asp.net server control)

The anchor tag:

```
<a href="~/Account Data/View.aspx" id="A2"  clientidmode="Static" runat="server" target="_self"  class="fancy"   style="line-height:16px"></a>
```

On click of this anchor tag my jQuery function gets called

```
$('a.fancy').fancybox({
            type: 'ajax',
            onComplete: fancyboxManager.initialize,
            padding: 0,
            overlayColor: '#000000',
            overlayOpacity: 0.62,
            scrolling: 'no',
            afterClose: function () {
               // location.reload();
                return;
            }
        });
```

The fancy box opens correctly but when I click on close button then it closes the pop up but none of the server control events are getting fired.
My requirement is that I can't referesh the page after close.

I guess this is happening due to break in the postback event caused by the fancy box

Comment: Please add some code and explain more of what behavior you expect.

Comment: fancybox is a clientside feature, why do you expect some kind of a postback after closing the dialog?
Can you please explain what is going on after popup close

Comment: Since the fancybox is breaking the postback event of page and so if we are not doing the postback then the control event of page is not getting triggered.

Comment: If you are using fancybox v1.3.4, then `afterClose` is not a valid option (that is for v2.x only), use `onClosed` instead

Comment: The issue is not with afterClose or onClosed...Issue is that after pop up is closed none of my server controls are working